# Rotating one image above another

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I have two images, one of a vehicle (a crane) and above it's one of it's arm, both are the same size.
Something like [this](http://www.gruasclaryfer.es/wp-content/uploads/DIAGRAMA-CARGA-PPT-ATT-600-50-TONELADAS.png)

I want to move (rotate) the arm, so I have to set the pivot on the crane.

My problem is that I can't wind a way to set the pivot.
To establish the pivot I was using something like this:

```
imageView_Arm.setPivotX((int)(imageView_Crane.getWidth() * 0.097));
imageView_Arm.setPivotY((int)(imageView_Crane.getHeight() * 0.92));
```

I thought that using proportions (0.0097...) would accomplish that the arm would rotate always on the same point of the crane on whatever resolution has the device.
It works on Nexus 5x (emulated device) but when I try a diferent Device like Nexus 4, or my own Device the pivot it's not where I expect to be.

I've tried too many things like changing the scaleType but I couldn't find a way.
I don't know if it's due to the layer or the imageView

Thank you!